# CMake Install target missing when generating VS2013 build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake

I'm using CMake Guid 3.0.0 and Visual Studio Express 2013 (64-bit). My CMakeLists.txt file does not generate an INSTALL target for my visual studio build. I can compile by building the ALL_BUILD project. I can then run the executable that's left in the Debug and Release folders. What do I need to add in order for the INSTALL target to build?

```
project(intraoperative_adjustments)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

if(POLICY CMP0020)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0020 NEW)
endif()

find_package(VTK COMPONENTS
  vtkCommonCore
  vtkFiltersCore
  vtkInfovisCore
  vtkInteractionStyle
  vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL
  vtkIOGeometry
  vtkViewsQt
)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

if("${VTK_QT_VERSION}" STREQUAL "")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "VTK was not built with Qt")
endif()

# Use the include path and library for Qt that is used by VTK.
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

# Set your files and resources here
set( Srcs main.cxx SimpleView.cxx )

set( Hdrs SimpleView.h )

set( MOC_Hdrs SimpleView.h )

set( UIs SimpleView.ui )

set( QRCs Icons/icons.qrc )


# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# The rest should just work (sure...)
if(VTK_QT_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "4")
  # We have ui files, this will bring in the macro: qt5_wrap_ui
  find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED QUIET)
  qt5_wrap_ui(UI_Srcs ${UIs})
  qt5_add_resources(QRC_Srcs ${QRCs} )

  source_group("Resources" FILES
    ${UIs}
    ${QRCs}
    ${EXE_ICON} # Not present
  )

  source_group("Generated" FILES
    ${UI_Srcs}
    ${MOC_Srcs}
    ${QRC_Srcs}
    ${QRC_Srcs}
  )

  add_executable(intraoperative_adjustments
    ${Srcs} ${Hdrs} ${UI_Srcs} ${MOC_Hdrs} ${QRC_Srcs})
  qt5_use_modules(intraoperative_adjustments Core Gui Widgets)
  target_link_libraries(intraoperative_adjustments ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
  include(${QT_USE_FILE})
  # Use what VTK built with
  set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE ${VTK_QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  set(QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE ${VTK_QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  set(QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE ${VTK_QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  qt4_wrap_ui(UI_Srcs ${UIs})
  qt4_wrap_cpp(MOC_Srcs ${MOC_Hdrs} )
  qt4_add_resources(QRC_Srcs ${QRCs})

  source_group("Resources" FILES
    ${UIs}
    ${QRCs}
    ${EXE_ICON} # Not present
  )

  source_group("Generated" FILES
    ${UI_Srcs}
    ${QRC_Srcs}
    ${QRC_Srcs}
  )

  add_definitions(-DQT_GUI_LIBS -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT3_SUPPORT)

  add_executable(intraoperative_adjustments
    ${Srcs} ${Hdrs} ${UI_Srcs} ${MOC_Hdrs} ${QRC_Srcs})
  target_link_libraries(intraoperative_adjustments
    ${QT_LIBRARIES}
    ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
  )
endif()
```

Comment: You need to create it first, see [install](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html) command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the INSTALL target using CMake's `install` command. See the according [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/install.html) for more details.